# Access Dispatch inside of Function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want my function below, "VerifyEmailResend" to have access to the two dispatch methods inside of mapDispatchToProps.  How do I do that?

VerifyEmailResend() is exported because i want it available to be called throughout my application.

This app is written in React using Redux.

I know normally the connect method is used, but connect is for react components specifically. Is there something similar here I am missing?

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'
import { api } from '../../api'
import { bool, func } from 'prop-types'
import VerifyEmailResent from './VerifyEmailResent'
import VerifyEmailVerified from './VerifyEmailVerified'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class VerifyEmail extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        // has the verify email been resent \\
        verifyEmailResent: bool,
        // have you already verified your email \\
        verifyEmailVerified: bool,
        // set status of verify email \\
        onSetVerifyEmailResent: func.isRequired,
        // set status of the email verified \\
        onSetVerifyEmailVerified: func.isRequired
    }

    resent = () => {
        const { onSetVerifyEmailResent } = this.props
        onSetVerifyEmailResent(false)
    }

    verified = () => {
        const { onSetVerifyEmailVerified } = this.props
        onSetVerifyEmailVerified(false)
    }

    render() {
        const { verifyEmailResent, verifyEmailVerified } = this.props
        return (
            <Fragment>
                {verifyEmailResent && (
                    <VerifyEmailResent action={this.resent} />
                )}
                {verifyEmailVerified && (
                    <VerifyEmailVerified action={this.verified} />
                )}
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    verifyEmailResent: state.eventListenerState.verifyEmailResent,
    verifyEmailVerified: state.eventListenerState.verifyEmailResent
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onSetVerifyEmailResent: verifyEmailResent =>
        dispatch({ type: 'VERIFY_EMAIL_RESENT_SET', verifyEmailResent }),
    onSetVerifyEmailVerified: verifyEmailVerified =>
        dispatch({ type: 'VERIFY_EMAIL_RESENT_VERIFIED', verifyEmailVerified })
})

const VerifyEmailResend = () => () => {
    api.user.resendEmailVerification().then(data => {
        if (data.resent) {
            //onSetVerifyEmailResent(true)
        }
        if (data.verified) {
            //onSetVerifyEmailVerified(false)
        }
    })
}

export connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(VerifyEmailResend)

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(VerifyEmail)
```

Comment: Where are you importing and calling VerifyEmailVerification(), in components right?

Comment: This line is invalid: `export connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(VerifyEmailResend)`

Comment: What you are looking for is a middleware. You don't need to connect a method to redux, but need to apply middlewares like redux-saga or redux-thunk. That will do what you want to achieve with that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you're confused at. But you can do it:

```
const VerifyEmailResend = () => {}
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(VerifyEmailResend)
```

As per you need a named export, you can do it like:

```
export {
  VerifyEmailResend: connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(VerifyEmailResend)
}
```

And you can import it normally like:

```
import { VerifyEmailResend } from '..'
```

And as per your comment, you can call it like followings depending your need of field:

```
{ VerifyEmailResend() }
```

Or like:

```
<VerifyEmailResend />
```

Comment: I thought I could do that, but I get the following error: "Declaration or statement expected." Highlighting the export and connect with error underlines.

Comment: was missing default between export and connect.

Comment: I have edited the post so you can see the entire file. As you can see I already have a default export, which I want to remain a default export.  Any way around this?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: You're welcome! I was just worried about my computer that just hung up (in fact, afraid of someone is hacking my pc - I see thick black border most of time in youtube and here in SO not sure why) :P

Comment: I have another question, if I decide to do my exports in my file as such:```export default {
    VerifyEmailResend: connect(
        null,
        mapDispatchToProps
    )(VerifyEmailResend),
    VerifyEmail: connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        mapDispatchToProps
    )(VerifyEmail)
}``` .  How do I import them? I try doing imports and the files say they are objects or are null.

Comment: You can't. Just remove the default keyword and will be fine.